# Line segment-triangle intersection algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection-theory, triangles, paper-request

currently in my project I'm using signed tetrahedron volume to check whether a line segment intersects a triangle. Initially I've found this approach in the great answer provided by professor O'Rourke: [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962225/how-to-know-if-a-line-segment-intersects-a-triangle-in-3d-space).

The method works perfectly fine, but my concern is if there are any scientific papers, which study and prove it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be reduced to solving the following linear equations in the variables $\lambda,\mu_1,\mu_2,\mu_3$: $$(1-\lambda)x_1+\lambda x_2=\mu_1 z_1+\mu_2 z_2+\mu_3 z_3,\ \mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3=1,$$
where the $x$’s are the points determining the line and  the $z$’s the vertices of the triangle.  In the generic case you will have a unique solution and the line will pass through the interior of the triangle if and only if the $\mu$‘s are all positive.  The other cases (line parallel to or lying in the plane of the triangle) can be dealt with easily.